# Ethereum contract chi gas token always uses 0 tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I'm trying to use chi gastoken in my contract to pay for gas, i use this modifier:

```
constructor(address _chi, address payable _owner) public {
    chi = IFreeFromUpTo(_chi);
    //0x0000000000004946c0e9F43F4Dee607b0eF1fA1c
    
    owner = _owner;
    authorizedUsersList[_owner] = true;
}

modifier discountCHI {
    uint gasStart = gasleft();
    _;
    uint gasSpent = 21000 + gasStart - gasleft() + 16 * msg.data.length;
    chi.freeFromUpTo(address(this), (gasSpent + 14154) / 41947);
}
```

I initialize chi as `chi = IFreeFromUpTo(_chi);` where _chi is the address of contract.

Whenever i decorate my function with `discountCHI` modifier no matter what the function does it always "uses" 0 chi.

It can be any function, like:

```
function countSomething(bytes memory data)
        payable
        public
        onlyUser
        discountCHI
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
    //Do important work here
    }
```

If i emit the amount passed to freeFromUpTo before the call itself it's not 0, am i missing any approvals or magic steps to make it work? Obviously, contract has more than 0 gas tokens.

Comment: Please be aware that the gas savings provided by the CHI token will likely be removed this year. Please see [this thread](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/3298) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Your contract needs to allow the transaction sender to spend CHI tokens belonging to the contract. To do this, **the contract** has to call `approve` method of the CHI token contract, which can be problematic because you'd have to code a method that does that.

Thus, it's better to use `freeUpTo` which spends `msg.sender`'s tokens.

Proof:

```
function freeFromUpTo(address from, uint256 value) public returns (uint256) {
    return freeFrom(from, Math.min(Math.min(value, balanceOf(from)), allowance(from, msg.sender)));
}
```

As you can see, the function takes the minimum of `value`, `balanceOf(from)`, or `allowance(from, msg.sender)`. Full source code is [here](https://github.com/1inch/chi/blob/master/contracts/ChiToken.sol).